# On mac os Mojave osquery not capturing events in osquery config plugin or config path

Tags: osquery

On mac os Mojave when try to capture process, file and network events using config plugin and logger plugin events lost. Also when try to capture events using config path (osquery.conf file) and logger plugin events lost. As soon as osquery service starts it will give event.

Those are there in osquery but it does not pass it to the logger. This one verified using osqueryi

Can anyone help here?